# One if else statement will not execute

Tags: c++, dictionary, if-statement

Below is the section I am having trouble with

```
        if(transition == *(vec.end()-1)) { //vec contains the ASCI code
            vec.pop_back();
            --vec_index;
            result.append(vec[vec_index]);
        } else if(colors.find(modified.substr(1)) == colors.end()) {
            cout << result << endl;
            cout << "\033[0;37m";
            cerr << "**ERROR: INVALID CLOSING COLOR TAG ON LINE: "
            //cerr << "**ERROR: OVERLAPPING CLOSING COLOR TAG ON LINE: "
            << nlines << endl;
            exit(0);
        } else {
            cout << result << endl;
            cout << "\033[0;37m";
            cerr << "**ERROR: INVALID CLOSING COLOR TAG ON LINE: "
            //cerr << "**ERROR: OVERLAPPING CLOSING COLOR TAG ON LINE: "
            << nlines << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
```

In the above code, my else-if statement does not seem to execute at all. What I am trying to do is when modified.substr(1) is not found in the map is print the first error otherwise (the color string is in the map but it's not the same one as the last one in the vector) print the "else" error. However, my else case is always printing. The reason why it's modified.substr(1) is because modified (in this case) starts with a /.

Comment: Give us more code - `vec`, `modified` (and probably some others) are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
transition = colors[modified.substr(1)];
```

will create an entry in `map<> color;` if **it's not existing** and value initialize it. That's why your `else if` condition will never be true. Use [map::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) instead of `operator []` to find the entry. Something like,

```
map<string,string>::const_iterator it = colors.find(modified.substr(1)];
```

And use `it` instead of `transition`. You can de-reference `it` (as `it->first` for key and `it->second` for string-value) when needed to get the underlying `string`.

Comment: transition should not play any part in it should it? For the if-else to become true at some point that is. The main if (with transition == *(vec.end()-1)) works fine.

Comment: @luli, no `transition` doesn't have much part; it's `colors[modified.substr(1)]` who adds an entry silently if it doesn't exist. That's why your `else if` is not executing. My remaining answer is to suggest to change your design.

Comment: Hi, I have changed it as you said, and used `code'if(*it == *(vec.end()-1)) {  However, compiler gives me an error for no match for operator ==

Comment: @luli, you have use `it->second` (not `*it`) in case of `map<>`. Here `it->first` gives you  key (`map<` **string**, `string>`) and then `it->second` gives you the value (`map<string,` **string** `>`).

Answer (score 1):

In your code `vec` is empty, so

```
if(transition == *(vec.end()-1))
```

leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry, prolly I shoudlve added my entire main. Is there a way to edit my OP? EDIT: Oh, found it, will update it very shortly